# AngularJs Select Not Updating When Model Updated

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to programmatically update the selected item from my controller and it's not working. When I click the submit button, all it does is clear out the select. What I expect is that the second option (Perth) gets selected.

Look at this plunker for more info. http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/

Thanks

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-app>
    <div>Number of datasets= {{datasets.length}}</div>
    <div>
        <select class="dataset" size="1" ng-model="selectedDataset">
            <option ng:repeat="dataset in datasets" value="{{dataset.name}}">
                <h3>{{dataset.name}}</h3>
            </option>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="Select()"></input>
</div>

function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.datasets = [{
        id: 'id-1',
        name: 'Brisbane'
    }, {
        id: 'id-2',
        name: 'Perth'
    }, {
        id: 'id-3',
        name: 'Melbourne'
    }];

    $scope.selectedDataset = 'id-1';

    $scope.Select = function () {
        alert('testing');
        $scope.selectedDataset = 'id-2';
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you have `ng:repeat` instead of `ng-repeat`...not that this will help the issue

Comment: yeah I realized, copied someone else's fiddle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.

```
<select class="dataset" size="1" ng-model="selectedDataset" 
    ng-options="dataset.id as dataset.name for dataset in datasets">
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/1/)

You can see the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)

Comment: Funny that the fix is so subtle... Thanks! I will mark as correct when the time limit is over.

Comment: I had a similar problem where my selectbox just goes blank when I change the model via another model-bound input:  `<select ng-model="item[key]" ng-options="option.ID as option.Name for option in item.Options"></select>` -- I thought it was due to the indexed model, but it seems to work fine as [simple version](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/ky5F4/11/) and [complex v1](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/ky5F4/12/) and [complex v2](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/ky5F4/13/).  Just sharing :)